# How to get the lat and lng of dragged waypoint

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am making this app where I let the user draw a waypoints route with google maps directions service and currently I am working on the edit route page - that is where the user can drag the waypoints of the route to reorder them. I am having trouble getting the lat and lng of the currently dragged waypoint.

How can I access the lat/lng of the dragged waypoint object on drag end?

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rendererOptions = {
  draggable: true
};
var phpway = <?php echo json_encode($phpway); ?>;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

var waypts = [];

for(var i = 0; i < phpway.length; i+=2){
  waypts.push(new google.maps.LatLng(Number(phpway[i]), Number(phpway[i+1]))); 
}

var start = waypts[0];
var end = waypts[waypts.length-1];
var mywaypts = [];
var pointsArray = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < waypts.length-1; i++) {

          mywaypts.push({
          location:waypts[i],
          stopover:true});
  }

var australia = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.274398, 133.775136);

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: australia
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));

  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    //computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
    calcRoute();

  });

  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {

  console.log(start);

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: mywaypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 'directions_changed' event handler, process through the "new" directions returned from:
`directionsDisplay.getDirections()`. The start/end locations of each leg are the waypoints (note that the end of the first leg will be the same point as the start of the second).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function () {
    document.getElementById('waypoints').innerHTML = "";
    var response = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
    var route = response.routes[0];
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
    for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
      document.getElementById('waypoints').innerHTML +=  legs[i].start_location.toUrlValue(6) +":";
      document.getElementById('waypoints').innerHTML +=  legs[i].end_location.toUrlValue(6)+"<br>";
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfdofnmg/)

Answer (score 0):

Inspect `var dirs = directionsDisplay.getDirections();`, maybe using `console.log(dirs);` to get a glance at the **request format**.

You will find the origin under `dirs.request.origin`, the destination under `dirs.request.destination` and the waypoints under `dirs.request.waypoints`.

To find the waypoint you have just ended dragging, keep the **previous request** (there should always be one, even before the first drag, since you first load the the route to be edited) and search for the differences in between this previous request and the current one via a simple iteration through the 'set of waypoints'. I suspect that there should be only one difference you find between the two (no matter if you introduce a new waypoint or you move an already existing one). That is your last dragged waypoint.